# Rails - passing form params to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Previously I had this same form but the button was a submit button that went to the search controller which used the params (i.e. the results of the checkboxes in the form) to search the database. This all worked great but I decided to use Ajax to display the results without a page refresh and so swapped to a javascript function (which makes an ajax call to the search controller, which now returns json) and now I need to pass the form params (i.e. the results of the checkboxes that I would have submitted to the controller before) to the javascript function and I can't work out how!

Code:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
    <% @price_filters.each do |price_filter| %>
        <ul>
          <%= check_box_tag "price_filters[]", price_filter %>
          <%= price_filter %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_tag "Search", onclick: "getSearchResults();", type: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

Perhaps something like `<%= button_tag "Search", onclick: "getSearchResults(form_parmams);", type: 'button' %>`

Comment: I recommend you consider submitting the form as format js (using `remote: true`) and then use javascript to process the data returned from the server.

Comment: Great call - thank you jvillian. I have done that and it's submitting to the controller with the correct params, without reloading the page (and correctly using ajax, which I checked with a request.xhr? in controller) BUT I can't get the javascript side to register the event with something like an '$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
console.log("do something here")
});' (doesn't do anything)

Comment: You'll need to use something like `$(document).ready` (it's different if you're using `spring`, which I never do). You can read more in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Comment: Have you tried with ajaxComplete? Because it is form $ submit and i'm not sure if it works with success:  (document).ajaxComplete(function() {
console.log("do something here")
});